# calculating number of days between a Ticket Opening and Closing

Tags: oracle11g

I have data like the below table:
I am struggling to get Number of days between the Start (Brown/Yellow) end (First Green)

**Example:**

For the Part # 111010, the days between Brown - First Green is 4.226388889 (08-12-2016 04:36 - 12-12-2016 10:02 )
and for the same Part # 111010,the days between YELLOW - First Green is 36.10555556  (17-08-2017 02:51 -  17-08-2017 02:51 )

```
+--------+------------------+--------+
| PartNO |       DATE       | STATUS |
+--------+------------------+--------+
| 111010 | 08-12-2016 04:36 | BROWN  |
| 111010 | 12-12-2016 10:02 | GREEN  |
| 111010 | 22-06-2017 08:04 | GREEN  |
| 111010 | 13-07-2017 05:30 | GREEN  |
| 111010 | 17-08-2017 02:51 | YELLOW |
| 111010 | 22-09-2017 05:23 | GREEN  |
| 111010 | 30-10-2017 03:48 | GREEN  |
| 111010 | 30-11-2017 05:41 | GREEN  |
| 111010 | 15-12-2017 04:19 | GREEN  |
+--------+------------------+--------+
```

I want the query to run on Oracle Database. My skills on Oracle query is very limited.  Can anyone please help me.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi';

Session altered.

SQL> with test (parno, datum, status) as
  2  (select 111010, to_date('08.12.2016 04:36', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'), 'brown' from dual union
  3   select 111010, to_date('12.12.2016 10:02', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'), 'green' from dual union
  4   select 111010, to_date('22.06.2017 08:04', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'), 'green' from dual union
  5   select 111010, to_date('13.07.2017 05:30', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'), 'green' from dual union
  6   select 111010, to_date('17.08.2017 02:51', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'), 'yellow' from dual union
  7   select 111010, to_date('22.09.2017 05:23', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'), 'green' from dual union
  8   select 111010, to_date('30.10.2017 03:48', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'), 'green' from dual union
  9   select 111010, to_date('30.11.2017 05:41', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'), 'green' from dual union
 10   select 111010, to_date('15.12.2017 04:19', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'), 'green' from dual
 11  ),
 12  what as
 13  (select status, lead(status) over (partition by parno order by datum) next_status,
 14          datum , lead(datum)  over (partition by parno order by datum) next_datum
 15   from test
 16  )
 17  select status, next_status, datum, next_datum, next_datum - datum diff
 18  from what
 19  where status in ('brown', 'yellow')
 20    and next_status = 'green'
 21  order by datum;

STATUS NEXT_S DATUM            NEXT_DATUM             DIFF
------ ------ ---------------- ---------------- ----------
brown  green  08.12.2016 04:36 12.12.2016 10:02 4,22638889
yellow green  17.08.2017 02:51 22.09.2017 05:23 36,1055556

SQL>
```

Comment: I am sorry to bother you again, when i run the query starting "(select status, lead(status)....." in SQL Navigator, I am getting results, however, when I input the same query in Power BI, i am getting following Error ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended. Do you have any idea why i am getting this error.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Power BI. Maybe it doesn't support analytic functions. If that's the case, you could try to create a **view** (in the database), using a query that works correctly. You'd then just use that view (as a simple SELECT statement) in Power BI, which wouldn't even know what code is written behind it.

Comment: Thank you.  Unfortunately, I have  Read only access to my Database.

Comment: Ask your DBA whether they can create it for you. A view is just a stored query, it won't consume any space and can't do any harm (at least, I think so).

Answer (score 0):

You need the use of the Lead function. you weren't very clear on your comparison condition, so my example will be to show the difference between the next line:

```
select PartNO, DATE, STATUS, LEAD(DATE,1,null) over (order by DATE) as NEXT_DATE,
 LEAD(DATE,1,null) over (order by DATE) - DATE as DAYS_DIFF
    from Table
```

If this isn't exactly what you need, feel free to adapt, or explain better your comparison conditions.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I am sorry that i haven't provided clear details.
I need to find the days between the Status change say Brown to Green, Green to yellow, Green to Brown, Yellow to Green.

Answer (score 0):

First add the previous status using `lag`, then filter records where that previous status is different from the current status, and finally get the date difference with `lead`. Here I assume your table is called `tbl` (adapt as needed):

```sql
with base (partno, prevStatus, status, dt) as (
    select partno,
           lag(status, 1, 'X') over (partition by partno order by "DATE") prevStatus, 
           status, 
           "DATE"
    from   tbl
),
filtered (partno, status, dt) as (
    select partno,
           status,
           dt
    from   base
    where  prevStatus <> status
)
select partno,
       status, 
       lead(dt) over (partition by partno order by dt) - dt diff
from   filtered
```

You'll get the date difference for every status change: just filter for the changes you are interested in afterwards (i.e. `status in ('BROWN', 'YELLOW')`).